# How to resize views for iphone 5 WITHOUT autolayout

Tags: xcode, resize, storyboard, iphone-5, autolayout

I'm using storyboard. I've been getting errors the past two weeks trying to get a custom page view controller to work http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=168. I finally figured out that this particular method does not work with auto layout.

So now I'm stuck, Is there a way to have the views resize to iphone 5, I have looked up different methods, but it seems that they are optimized for xibs (which i'm not using).

At the very least, how would I remove support for iphone 5, because now when I run the iphone 5 simulator, all the pixels are added to the left which off centers my app :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is going to depend on exactly what you are wanting to do, but here is how I do it. In order to make my layout work with the iPhone 5, I measure from the bottom for any items that I want near the bottom of the screen:

```
CGRect settingsButtonFrame = CGRectMake(10, self.view.frame.size.height - 80, 26, 26);
```

Comment: This goes into the .h? sorry im a noob when it comes to xcode

Comment: No, you would need to use this type of code for each frame that you create for your view and any objects on your view.

Comment: and how would I remove iphone 5 support completely?

Comment: I don't believe that that is possible.

Comment: Oh, I meant like how to keep the aspect ratio to 960x640 and just have black bars on the side, I removed the i586 launch image, but it still tries to resize full screen for iphone 5.